# How can create a telescope with migrate

Tags: php, laravel, telescope

I have successfully installed Telescope:

```
C:\Users\USER\p3>php artisan telescope:install
Publishing Telescope Service Provider...
Publishing Telescope Assets...
Publishing Telescope Configuration...
Telescope scaffolding installed successfully.
```

However, when I use: `php artisan migrate`, it says nothing was migrated. I also tried `php artisan migrate:fresh`, all the table were created but no telescope!!

```
C:\Users\USER\p3>php artisan migrate
Nothing to migrate.
```

Please any help?

Comment: You say you installed, but you've only shown us 1 of the 2 [installation commands](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/telescope#installation).  I assume the 2nd would not work without the first, but, just to rule out the obvious - did you `composer require laravel/telescope`?